# Multiple values of regionCode field

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Can I set multiple values of regionCode parameter when doing request to get search list? I have tried "DE,GB,US", but it does not work.

Comment: While i understand your question just fine.  Its really best to add the code you are using and describe the problem this will assist other users in finding your question and maybe getting help with a similar issue.   Welcome to stack.

Answer (score 0):

[search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) method

> q
> The q parameter specifies the query term to search for.
>
> Your request can also use the Boolean NOT (-) and OR (|) operators to exclude videos or to find videos that are associated with one of several search terms. For example, to search for videos matching either "boating" or "sailing", set the q parameter value to boating|sailing. Similarly, to search for videos matching either "boating" or "sailing" but not "fishing", set the q parameter value to boating|sailing -fishing. Note that the pipe character must be URL-escaped when it is sent in your API request. The URL-escaped value for the pipe character is %7C.

does a full text search on the title and description of a video only.

> regionCode string
>
> The regionCode parameter instructs the API to return search results for videos that can be viewed in the specified country. The parameter value is an ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code.

is a single regon code and must be [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](https://www.iso.org/iso-3166-country-codes.html) so you can only send one at a time.  There is nothing stopping you from making three requests one for each of your country codes.

Comment: yes, I'm making three requests one for each of region code. I need to check and get all upcoming broadcasts of more then 1500 channels every hour and it causes issue with quotas. And number of channels will be increased.

Comment: request for an extension of your quota.  There is no other option.